# Can not convert Html content to Pdf

Tags: sharepoint-online

Hi i am trying to convert html contents to pdf files using JsPDF but it is convert the pdf file. But the file contains empty pdf file. There is no content to displayed like header image and date.  Could any body advice to me what is the problem?

```js
 
 $("#btn-add").on('click', function () {
            var hDate ="Test";
            $('#heDate').html(hDate);
            var pdf = new jsPDF();
            var specialElementHandlers = {
            '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
                         return true;
                     }
                 };
         pdf.fromHTML($('#cover').html(), 15, 15, {
                     'width': 170,
                     'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
                 });
               pdf.save('sample-file.pdf');
         
             }  

        });
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/CoverLetter.js"></script> 
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-JmvOoLtYsmqlsWxa7mDSLMwa6dZ9rrIdtrrVYRnDRH0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jspdf/1.2.61/jspdf.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/html2canvas.js"></script>
          
 <div id="cover" class="formarea">
 <table> 
 <tr> 
   <td><img src="../Images/Header.png" /></td>
 </tr>
  <tr>  
    <td>
        <div> 
            <label> Date: </label>
            <label id="heDate">  </label>
        </div>
        <div id="editor"></div>
   </td>
  </tr> 
</table> 
</div>  

<table> 
   
   <tr>       
    <td>
      
      <button  type="button" id="btn-add"  class="btn">Create Letter</button> 
     </td>       
   </tr>   
    
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My test code which works in my local.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.0.272/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#btn-add").on('click', function () {
                var hDate = "Test";
                $('#heDate').html(hDate);
                var pdf = new jsPDF();
                var specialElementHandlers = {
                    '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
                        return true;
                    }
                };                
                pdf.fromHTML($('#cover')[0], 15, 15, {
                    'width': 170,
                    'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
                },
                function (dispose) {
                    // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF 
                    // this allow the insertion of new lines after html
                    pdf.save('Test.pdf');
                });

            });
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="cover" class="formarea">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="../Images/Header.png" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <label> Date: </label>
                        <label id="heDate">  </label>
                    </div>
                    <div id="editor"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <table>

        <tr>
            <td>

                <button type="button" id="btn-add" class="btn">Create Letter</button>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```